# Rails 4 shallow nesting UrlGenerationError, missing required keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I'm trying shallow nested resources for the first time and having a little trouble with one my index routes.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :sites, shallow: true do
  resources :visits
end
```

The error I get is in my `visits#show` page's back button:

`<%= link_to 'Back', site_visits_path(@site) %>`

`No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"visits", :site_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:site_id]`

In the `index` action of my `VisitsController` I set`@site` as follows:

```
@site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
```

However it's saying my `:site_id` is nil and I'm not sure how to set this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that like:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', site_visits_path(:site_id => @site.id) %>
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, got this error:

`undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`


I think the way I'm setting `@site` in my controller must be changed somehow as the errors I'm getting are saying my `@site` is nil.

`@site = Site.find(params[:site_id])` works when I use full deep nesting but in this shallow nesting case it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for the help though I'll give you a checkmark if nothing else comes up since I can't upvote yet.

Comment: I figured it out. There is no `:site_id` in my URL when using shallow nesting because the page is at `localhost:3000/visits/m`, rather than the usual `localhost:3000/sites/n/visits/m`. Thus in the `show` action of my controller, I first set `@visit = Visit.find(params[:id])` then `@site = @visit.site` to get back to the index of visits related to that Site!